# Change component attribute from managedbean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to change a primefaces component's attribute from managedbean. I have a component selectCheckboxMenu implemented like :

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{formBean.selectedMovies}" label="Movies" filter="true" filterText="Filter" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:220px">  
    <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.movies}" />
    <p:ajax update="treeTableForm" listener="#{formBean.listenMovieChange}" />  
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

I want to change the attribute label of this component from managedbean in method listenMovieChange. How can I do this? The reason I am trying this approach is that, I have a lot of selectCheckboxMenu components in a page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a list of bound components to be able to edit them at server side. In order to get which one you have to choose depending on the fired ajax event, just send the component itself as a method argument (supposing you're using EL 2.2):

```java
//You'll need to initialize them setting the proper values
private List<SelectCheckBoxMenu> checkBoxes;

//GETTER AND SETTER

public void listenMovieChange(SelectCheckBoxMenu menuToProcess){
    menuToProcess.setLabel(newLabel());
}
```

```xml
<ui:repeat var="checkboxmenu" value="#{formBean.checkBoxes}">

    <p:selectCheckboxMenu
        filter="true" filterText="Filter" filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
        panelStyle="width:220px" binding="#{checkboxmenu}">  
        <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.movies}" />
        <p:ajax update="treeTableForm" listener="#{formBean.listenMovieChange(checkboxmenu)}" />  
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>

</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I could do that, but what would I do if i have a lot of these components in the same page, user can increase the number of these components.

Comment: Then you'll not have the problem only with the label itself, but with the whole component. You should then create a list of bound [SelectCheckBoxMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/component/selectcheckboxmenu/SelectCheckboxMenu.html). Have a look to my edit.